# How to make a React multi-step form work with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working to learn React + ReactRouter to build a multi-step form. I got the example working here: https://www.viget.com/articles/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react

The problem is this example doesn't use ReactRouter so the URL never changes during the form. The author mentions "You could set each step to a custom route" however, I haven't been able to figure out how to get that to work. How can you update the current render process to work with ReactRouter?

```
render: function() {
    switch (this.state.step) {
        case 1:
    return <AccountFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                          nextStep={this.nextStep}
                          saveValues={this.saveValues} />
        case 2:
    return <SurveyFields  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                          nextStep={this.nextStep}
                          previousStep={this.previousStep}
                          saveValues={this.saveValues} />
        case 3:
    return <Confirmation  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                          previousStep={this.previousStep}
                          submitRegistration={this.submitRegistration} />
        case 4:
    return <Success fieldValues={fieldValues} />
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
  render: function() {
        switch (this.state.step) {
            case 1:
        return <AccountFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                              nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              saveValues={this.saveValues} />
            case 2:
                       browserHistory.push('/surveyfields')
            case 3:
                      browserHistory.push('/confirmation')
            case 4:
                       browserHistory.push('/success')
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

```
..
        case 2:
            <Route path="/surveyfields" component={SurveyFields}/>
..

var Welcome = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/welcome' component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path='/stuff' component={Stuff} />
          <Route path='/features' component={Features} />
          <Route path='/surveyfields' component={SurveyFields} />

        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you route them like this, transitioning from say, `/surveyfields` to `/success` wont affect affect the state of the `Survey` component at all.

```
<Route path="/surveyfields" component={Survey}/>
<Route path="/confirmation" component={Survey}/>
<Route path="/success" component={Survey}/>
```

React Router will however update the props and trigger a render. If you want to render different things depending on URL, have this in the `render` method.

```
if(this.props.location.pathname==="/surveyfields")
   return (
     <span>
       survey things
       <Button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/confirmation")}>next page</Button>
   </span>)
if(this.props.location.pathname==="/confirmation")
   return <span>do you want to do this</span>
```

Clicking the button will navigate to the next page. The `location` and `history` props are inserted by React router for Route components.

Comment: Thanks. I changed `browserHistory.push('/surveyfields')` to `<Route path="/surveyfields" component={SurveyFields}/>` - While that does load the React component SurveyFields, it does not change the URL which is my goal with use react router... Why doesn't the route URL change? UPDATED above

Comment: You should not change state or URL inside a render method, imagine an infinite loop when you change state, you trigger a render, which in turn changes state... I would change URL state in `this.saveValues` method

Comment: And use Route only in the router, putting it elsewhere is undefined behaviour. So `case 2: return <FieldsComponent a={b}/>`

Comment: are you suggesting I use `browserHistory.push('/surveyfields')` in SaveValues? I'm trying to imagine how to put your suggestions together into a implementation. Would you mind updating your answer with an example and then I can accept? Thanks

Comment: I updated the example to show how the same `Survey` instance renders different content based on its URL. And also how to trigger a route change with a simple click. You start at `/surveyfields`, which then makes Survey instance render content for step 1. Then you click a button that takes you to `/confirmation`, which  makes Survey instance renders content for step 2.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting: `Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure your component is one which is in a `Route`? Try exploring all props passed to that component.